# InflateException when trying to use a Snackbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-snackbar

I have a `Snackbar`, which is supposed to show in case no resorts are found after making a request to a server for data. Every time the `Snackbar` needs to be shown I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:143)
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:565)
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:432)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:143) 
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:565) 
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:432) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:143) 
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:565) 
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:432) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100b0 a=-1}
                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:482)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1043)
                                                                 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
                                                                 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
                                                                 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:101)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:143) 
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:565) 
                                                                 at com.tripoffbeat.Result$LoadAllResorts.doInBackground(Result.java:432) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My current class extends `ListActivity` and is implementing a `ActionBar`.

The line where it is giving an error:

```
pDialog.dismiss();
                Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "No resorts found", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
                                Intent i = new Intent(Result.this, OptionList.class);
                                i.putExtras(data);
                                setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark ))
                        .show();
```

If I replace the Snackbar message with a Toast it works fine.

XML for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="All resorts and prices"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="430dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/cover_overlay"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:text="Sort by:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation='horizontal'>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/sort_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/sort_alpha"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:duplicateParentState="false"
                    android:text="Alphabetically"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/sort_states"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:duplicateParentState="false"
                    android:text="State"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/sort_city"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Cities" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/sort_dist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Distance" />

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Parent layout code:

```
parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

The `Snackbar` worked perfectly before I added the action bar.

For this activity I'm using a `Theme.Holo.Light.ActionBar`
Android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Result"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName="com.tripoffbeat.OptionList"/>
```

In my `styles.xml` my theme is `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`.

Comment: post your xml also

Comment: Done @quicklearner

Comment: use CoordinatorLayout as the parent layout , check this example http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/

Comment: I will try with that but the Snackbar worked perfectly before I added the action bar. Any thoughts on that? @quicklearner

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Done @azizbekian

Comment: Are you performing `Snackbar.make()` from a background thread (e.g. in your `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()`)?

Comment: Yes I am @azizbekian

Comment: That's your problem. You shouldn't perform UI related action from background thread. Wait until `onPostExecute()` or perform that action in `onProgressUpdate()`.

Comment: I tried that and still got the same error :/ @azizbekian

Comment: Can you also post your `styles.xml`?

Comment: Done @azizbekian

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When `Snackbar` inflates [its content layout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/layout/design_layout_snackbar_include.xml#L1), it [cannot inflate a `Button`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/layout/design_layout_snackbar_include.xml#L50) from that layout, because it lacks to find `?attr/colorAccent` from the theme of the current context. That's happening, because the theme of your activity is not a descendant of `AppCompat` theme.

So, instead of:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

apply some *appcompatish* theme. Removing that line from manifest would resolve your error, assuming the theme of your application is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Comment: Yess that does it! Thanks!

Comment: Is changing the theme the only way around this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was about using the wrong context, so I was using `applicationContext` instead of `this@LoginActivity` and the solution was to reverse this.